# Why is markdown finding weird characters in my exported wordpress xml file?

Tags: django, wordpress, markdown

Mac OSX 10.7
Python 2.7
Django 1.3
Markdown 2.0.3

I am trying to migrate from a wordpress blog to a django-powered one. I am using pigmonkey's [django-basic-apps](https://github.com/pigmonkey/django-basic-apps) for it's xml parsing script, but every time I attempt it, markdown keeps raising "markdown.MarkdownException: UnicodeDecodeError: Markdown only accepts unicode or ascii input."

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mycomputer/.virtualenvs/zachswhite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_basic_apps-0.8-py2.7.egg/basic/blog/management/commands/wordpress_import.py", line 100, in handle
    post.save()
  File "/Users/mycomputer/.virtualenvs/zachswhite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_basic_apps-0.8-py2.7.egg/basic/blog/models.py", line 77, in save
    self.body_rendered = mark_safe(formatter(self.body_rendered, filter_name=self.markup))
  File "/Users/mycomputer/.virtualenvs/zachswhite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_markup-0.3-py2.7.egg/django_markup/markup.py", line 90, in __call__
    return filter_class().render(text, **filter_kwargs)
  File "/Users/mycomputer/.virtualenvs/zachswhite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_markup-0.3-py2.7.egg/django_markup/filter/markdown_filter.py", line 21, in render
    text = markdown(text, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mycomputer/.virtualenvs/zachswhite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markdown/__init__.py", line 598, in markdown
    return md.convert(text)
  File "/Users/mycomputer/.virtualenvs/zachswhite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markdown/__init__.py", line 377, in convert
    message(CRITICAL, 'UnicodeDecodeError: Markdown only accepts unicode or ascii input.')
  File "/Users/mycomputer/.virtualenvs/zachswhite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markdown/__init__.py", line 112, in message
    raise MarkdownException, text
markdown.MarkdownException: UnicodeDecodeError: Markdown only accepts unicode or ascii input.
```

There's nothing outside unicode in there, that I've found maybe you guys would have better luck.

I can upload the xml file too, if that would help

Comment: [Link to xml file](http://www.zachswhite.com/blog/zachswhiteblog.xml)

Comment: What is the encoding of the XML file?

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding to include a Byte Order Mark?

Comment: I just encoded it in Notepad++ on my windows partition as "utf-8" as opposed to "utf-8 without BOM" and it raises the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed as of my most recent commit to my fork of django-basic-apps. The error was caused by passing the post's body and tease through the inline parser before passing it to Markdown (which is necessary for [other reasons](https://github.com/pigmonkey/django-vellum/commit/bb8ba70a866ddf6c55af0257093415f3dc7d98bc)). I don't fully understand why the error was being thrown, but you can read today's commit message for what I do know:
https://github.com/pigmonkey/django-vellum/commit/1d5fb4743a7fc34e4b6cd415144ad232bbc3f0ad

By the way, I just noticed this question today as I was doing some Googling, trying to understand this error. For future reference, if you contact me through Github, or through my website, or create an Issue for the project on Github, or email me, I'll probably respond a lot faster! I'm always interested to hear about any bugs found in my projects.